# Difference between build and "assign" for a child association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, build, associations, assign

I'm curious what the difference is between using "build" or just directly assigning a child for associations?

Assume I have a @user instance already, and I just want to create the child association to an organization:

**Approach 1:**

```
@organization = Organization.new
@organization.build_user(@user.attributes)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
@organization = Organization.new
@organization.user = @user
```

Both do the same thing, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `Organization` has a `User`, then assigning an association directly requires `@user` to be a `User` object to work or else it's prone to throwing an error. `build` handles the association and sets the foreign keys automatically. e.g.

Will work:

```
@organization.build_user({username: "User"})
```

Will work:

```
@organization.user = User.new(username: "User")
```

Won't work:

```
@organization.user = {username: "User"}
```

Comment: OK, so as long as @user is a legitimate object, then the two approaches are completely the same? That's what I would expect, just want to make sure. Thanks!